# mysql AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute 'unpack_from'

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I use `mysql.connector` to connect to `mysql`, here is my Python sentence:

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = 'password', database = 'test', use_unicode = True)`
```

but there is an error, here is the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonConnectToMySQL.py", line 6, in <module>
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = 'hankenqqqq', database = 'test', use_unicode = True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 162, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 129, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 454, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 418, in _open_connection
    self._do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 141, in _do_handshake
    packet = self._socket.recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 235, in recv_plain
    payload_len = struct.unpack_from(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'unpack_from'`
```

and here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
#-*-coding:utf8-*-

import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = 'password', database = 'test', use_unicode = True)

cursor = conn.cursor()    
cursor.execute('create table user (id varchar(20) primary key, name varchar(20))')

cursor.execute('insert into user(id, name) values (%s, %s)', ['1', 'Mary'])
print cursor.rowcount

conn.commit()
cursor.close()

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from user where id = %s', '1')

values = cursor.fetchall()
print values

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

I have create database `test` in `mysql`
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which Python version are you using?

struct is a built-in library, and the unpack_from method was included in Python version 2.5.

If you are using an older version of Python consider upgrading to version 2.7 or 3.X.

If it is not possible for you to move to a newer version, you can try with an older version of the connector (version 1.0 is compatible with Python 2.4). You can download older versions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)

Comment: My Python version is 2.7.6， and the version of mysql.connector is 2.0.4.  so I think it is not the problem of version

Comment: I have found the reason of this problem, It is because that I write a file which name is struct.py, so when I import struct, it occurs a error.Thank you for help me!

Comment: @ken your last comment was the answer for me. If you make it a real answer rather than a comment, I will upvote it.